# How to change the font color for the entire text in TextWrangler (Mac)?

Tags: mac, textwrangler

The usual “Preferences > Editor Defaults.” doesn't work.

With a file open, I’ve also tried changing the color through “View > Text Display > Show Fonts.” but no luck.

Can the font color be changed?